# How to stop logging Login failure javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException on JBOSS 7

Tags: authentication, jsf-2, jboss7.x, jaas

in my jsf2 project I'm using jaas on jboss 7.1, when I login incorrect password/id, jboss throws: `ERROR [org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager] javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: Password Incorrect/Password Required`

I coded a ExceptionHandlerFactory but ExceptionHandlerFactory is called after exception is logging in jboss console, anyone know how I can catch this exception? I want catch it before it was logging in console and I want print a code error like *Exception: A-0014*

Comment: in jboss standalone.xml <security-domain ... I'm using  <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.LdapLoginModule" and  <module-option name="java.naming.factory.initial" value="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"/> I think that if one of these classes throws this exception I can't catch it because this exception is not generate on my project, is this correct? then I'd have to create my on security class extended LdapLoginModule or something

Answer (score 0):

There is effectively no programmatic way to catch this exception.

This is a management challenge given that every single instance of a bad user/password call is going to dump a huge stack-trace and fill up the container logs at the ERROR level.

I have a similar situation with a custom login-module that extends org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.
At some point, the overriden superclass method "validatePassword" returns false.
This gets trapped by the parent implementation of the "login()" method, which (incorrectly) declares "javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: Password Incorrect/Password Required". In my case the network connection was never made to the authenticating service.

So what is actually happening is that the org.jboss.security.authentication.JBossCachedAuthenticationManager class (internal) is the culprit doing the logging (at the ERROR level, so is problematic to filter out).

JBoss as of July 2012 was tracking (and still is as of JBoss AS 7.1.2) an "enhancement" to allow trapping of this. It is problematic for remote invocation type operations as well.

Answer (score -2):

hope this [Jboss comunity answer](https://community.jboss.org/message/643858) link will help you to hadle your exception

you can throw you message in login method **like Exception: A-0014**

Comment: Please flesh out the concrete answer in the answer itself instead of posting a link to an unclear discussion forum topic. Otherwise, better post it as a comment on the question (after having earned a minimum of 50 reputation in order to post comments on other's posts).

Comment: @BalusC may be you are correct but i tried the same code written there and i am able to handle (log) failed authentication attempt.